# How to add images to tailwind card from API

Tags: reactjs, image, api, react-hooks, axios

I am trying to edit a project from github to learn how to call data from an API. Everything works fine so far and I have managed to change the card to a nice tailwind card. However, I am struggling to add an image.

Here is the code

```
const CardApi = ({ api }) => {
  const renderDetail = (text, field) => <p>{text}: <span className="font-semibold">{api[field] || '-'}</span></p>

  return (
 
        <div class="max-w-sm bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="rounded-t-lg" src="/docs/images/blog/image-1.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
    <div class="p-5">
        <a href="#">
            <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Noteworthy technology acquisitions 2021</h5>
        </a>
        <p class="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
          {renderDetail('title', 'title')}
         {renderDetail('brand', 'brand')}
        {renderDetail('Description', 'description')}
        {renderDetail('price', 'price')}
        {renderDetail('rating', 'rating')}
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white bg-blue-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">
            Read more
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-4 h-4 ml-2 -mr-1" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.293 3.293a1 1 0 011.414 0l6 6a1 1 0 010 1.414l-6 6a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L14.586 11H3a1 1 0 110-2h11.586l-4.293-4.293a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

     

  )
}

export default CardApi
```

I tried to edit by using the api results by trying to call the "thumbnail" just like I have done with "tile" etc

"products": **[{**

"id": **1**,

"title": "iPhone 9",

"thumbnail": "https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/thumbnail.jpg",

"images": **[**"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/1.jpg",

"https://i.dummyjson.com/data/products/1/2.jpg

I edited by adding image to  **renderDetail** and adding "thumbnail" to the image class on the css but it didn't work. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

```
const CardApi = ({ api }) => {
  const renderDetail = (image,text, field) => <p>{text}: <span className="font-semibold">{api[field] || '-'}</span></p>
```

```
<img class="rounded-t-lg" src={thumbnail}" />
```